# Is there a version of set_as_top_level() for c#?

Tags: c#, godot, godot4

I'm coding a game in Godot 4 using c#, and I'm trying to use the set_as_top_level() command for a node2D, but I get told that the command doesn't exist in the scope

The block of code for context:

```
public override void _Ready()
    {
        Timer timer = (Timer)GetNode("Timer");
        Sprite2D sprite = (Sprite2D)GetNode("Sprite2D");
        timer.Start(lifetime/60f);
        sprite.LookAt(GetGlobalMousePosition());
        direction = GetGlobalMousePosition();
        SetAsTopLevel(true);
    }
```

I've tried SetAsTopLevel() and set_as_top_level(), but neither are working

Answer (score 1):

[Look at the comment here](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/w8p0fo/set_as_toplevel_in_godot_4/)

set_as_top_level was removed in Godot 4. You can now directly use the property top_level. The equivalent in C# is TopLevel. So your code would look like this:

```
public override void _Ready()
{
    Timer timer = (Timer)GetNode("Timer");
    Sprite2D sprite = (Sprite2D)GetNode("Sprite2D");
    timer.Start(lifetime/60f);
    sprite.LookAt(GetGlobalMousePosition());
    direction = GetGlobalMousePosition();
    TopLevel = true;
}
```